# Getting error - The version of EdmItemCollection must match the version of StoreItemCollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, .net-3.5, .net-4.5

I have created the EDM model using Visual Studio 2010 with .Net framework 3.5.
Now I have upgraded my project to Visual Studio 2012 with .Net framework 4.5. My project got compiled successfully but I am getting the below error in runtime.

```
System.Data.MappingException : Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
error 2102: The version of EdmItemCollection must match the version of StoreItemCollection.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `<edmx:Edmx>` tag in the EDMX xml. In my case the SSDL and MSL files are showing different versions after migration. I regenerated the MSL, SSDL and CSDL files and the problem got solved.